# Kivy canvas.clear() not clearing the canvas

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have followed the [widget tutorial for Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/firstwidget.html), but I cannot get the canvas to clear after painting (from their 'a simple paint app' tutorial), unless I resize the window after pressing the clear button. Please help. I am using kivy v1.10.1 and python v3.7.0. on windows 10 64-bit OS. Further, a widget in scatter mode leaves a trace when you drag to a new position, this also clears when resizing the window. See code below:

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works correctly, I have corrected the indentation of your code. What version of kivy do you have?

Comment: OK, probably more of a specific problem to my setup then. I'm using v1.10.1

Comment: It works for me correctly in Linux with kivy 1.10.1.

Comment: Can you provide the run log of kivy in debug mode? It might depend of the gl backend used, check if you installed with angle or glew provider, and if the sdl2 window provider is used, or something else. Did you follow the documentation to install?

Comment: Indeed, I followed the documentation for installation. I am now using a different computer and don't have the issue. I will provide the log when I am next back at that computer. Thanks for your help.