# How can I fix a duplication error in my Kivy app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I made simple game using python and Kivy. One day when I ran the code I got duplication graphics problem. Basically every object on the screen appears multiple times ( as if its drawing all the objects on the screen over and over again). The program used to run fine but one day this problem just started occurring.

I've tried running the same code on a friends computer and it works fine so it could be hardware related. ( I have an Alienware 17 r4 and he has a Macbook)  Previous versions of my code that didn't have the problem do have it now.

Edit: I think the problem has to do with clear canvas not functioning properly. I found a question which I think describes the same problem:

[Kivy canvas.clear() not clearing the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561692/kivy-canvas-clear-not-clearing-the-canvas)

However that question wasn't answered. Manually resizing the screen makes the problem disappear as mentioned in the question I linked

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
kivy.require('1.0.6')  # replace with your current kivy version !

class ConnectApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv_file

class Menu(Screen):
    pass

class Setting(Screen):
    pass

class Main(Screen):
    board = [
        [2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]
    ]
    hold_piece: bool = False
    temp = 0
    move_no = 0

    P1win = False
    P2win = False

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_canvas)
        self.bind(size=self.update_canvas)
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]
            for i in self.board:
                for index in get_indexes(1, i):
                    Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
                    Ellipse(pos=(self.size[0] * index * 0.25, self.size[1] * self.board.index(i) * 0.25 + self.size[1]*0.125),
                            size=(self.size[0] * 0.25, self.size[1] * 0.25))
                for index in get_indexes(2, i):
                    Color(0, 0, 1, 1)
                    Ellipse(pos=(self.size[0] * index * 0.25, self.size[1] * self.board.index(i) * 0.25 + self.size[1]*0.125),
                            size=(self.size[0] * 0.25, self.size[1] * 0.25))
            mylabel = CoreLabel(text="Reset", font_size=25, color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            mylabel.refresh()
            texture = mylabel.texture
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.size[0] * 0.8, self.size[1] * 0.65), size=(self.size[0] * 0.15, self.size[1] * 0.15), texture=texture)
            label2 = CoreLabel(text="Menu", font_size=25, color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            label2.refresh()
            texture = label2.texture
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(self.size[0] * 0.8, self.size[1] * 0.25), size=(self.size[0] * 0.15, self.size[1] * 0.15), texture=texture)

    def press(self, row, col):
        if self.move_no % 2 == 0:
            if self.board[row][col] == 2 and not self.hold_piece:
                self.temp = self.board[row][col]
                self.board[row][col] = 0
                self.hold_piece = True
            elif self.board[row][col] == 0 and self.hold_piece:
                self.board[row][col] = self.temp
                self.temp = 0
                self.hold_piece = False
                self.update_canvas()
                self.move_no += 1
            else:
                pass
        else:
            if self.board[row][col] == 1 and not self.hold_piece:
                self.temp = self.board[row][col]
                self.board[row][col] = 0
                self.hold_piece = True
            elif self.board[row][col] == 0 and self.hold_piece:
                self.board[row][col] = self.temp
                self.temp = 0
                self.hold_piece = False
                self.update_canvas()
                self.move_no += 1
                self.checkWin()
                self.wincon()
            else:
                pass

    def reset(self):

        self.board = [
        [2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]

        self.move_no = 0
        self.update_canvas()

    def checkWin(self):

        if self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][0] == self.board[2][0] == 1 or self.board[0][1] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][1] == 1 or self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][2] == self.board[2][2] == 1:
            self.P1win = True
        elif self.board[0][0] == self.board[0][1] == self.board[0][2] == 1 or self.board[1][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[1][2] == 1:
            self.P1win = True
        elif self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2] == 1 or self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] == 1:
            self.P1win = True
        elif self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][0] == self.board[2][0] == 2 or self.board[0][1] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][1] == 2 or self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][2] == self.board[2][2] == 2:
            self.P2win = True
        elif self.board[2][0] == self.board[2][1] == self.board[2][2] == 2 or self.board[1][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[1][2] == 2:
            self.P2win = True
        elif self.board[0][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][2] == 2 or self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] == 2:
            self.P2win = True
        else:
            pass

    def wincon(self):
        if self.P1win:
            print("Player 2 wins")
            pop(2)
        elif self.P2win:
            print("Player 1 wins")
            pop(1)
        else:
            pass

class p1_win():
    pass

class p2_win():
    pass

def pop(num):
    if num == 1:
        show = p1_win()
        popup = Popup(content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size =(400, 400))
    else:
        show = p2_win()
        popup = Popup(content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    popup.open()

class WinManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv_file = Builder.load_string("""
WinManager:
    Menu:
    Main:
    Setting:

<Menu>:
    name: "menu"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.7}
            text: "Connect 3"
            font_size: 40
            background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            background_color: 0.4,1,0.4 ,1
            size_hint: 0.34, 0.16
            pos_hint: {"x":0.33, "y":0.3}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "main"
        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            background_color: 0.4, 1, 0.4, 1
            size_hint: 0.34, 0.16
            pos_hint: {"x":0.33, "y":0.1}
            on_press: root.manager.current = "setting"


<Main>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.8 , "y":0.65}
            on_press: root.reset()
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.8 , "y":0.25}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = "menu"
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.15

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0 , "y":0.125}
            text: "A1"
            on_press: root.press(0, 0)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0 , "y":0.375}
            text: "A2"
            on_press: root.press(1, 0)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0 , "y":0.625}
            text: "A3"
            on_press: root.press(2, 0)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.25 , "y":0.125}
            text: "B1"
            on_press: root.press(0, 1)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.25 , "y":0.375}
            text: "B2"
            on_press: root.press(1, 1)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.25 , "y":0.625}
            text: "B3"
            on_press: root.press(2, 1)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5 , "y":0.125}
            text: "C1"
            on_press: root.press(0, 2)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5 , "y":0.375}
            text: "C2"
            on_press: root.press(1, 2)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5 , "y":0.625}
            text: "C3"
            on_press: root.press(2, 2)
            size_hint:0.25, 0.25

<Setting>:
    name: "setting"
    Label:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.25
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.7}
        text: "I'm not smart enough to add settings"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        background_color: 0.4,1,0.4 ,1
        size_hint: 0.34, 0.16
        pos_hint: {"x":0.33, "y":0.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.current = "menu"
""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Window.fullscreen = True
    ConnectApp().run()
```

This is the output in the terminal if it helps:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\muham\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-10-30_4.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.17
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.9
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew_dev" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2_dev" 0.1.22
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\muham\PycharmProjects\Connect3\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\muham\PycharmProjects\Connect3\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.6859'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.6859'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

This is what appears on the screen:

Screenshot of screen when I run code

[image]

Comment: I don't see that problem either. Check that there is not a `connect.kv` file in the same folder with your above code.

Comment: I recommend you create a new folder where you just place the .py and then run your program to avoid unreasonable errors like an external .kv. If the error persists even by implementing my previous recommendation then it is probably a kivy bug so it is recommended that you report it.

Answer (score 0):

Running your game I got this three screens

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

As [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson) said, you need to look for kivy files (.kv) to find conflicts like windows with two different kind of Buttons. ¿Why? Because kivy runs the code and search for same name of the file (.py) but with .kv extension.

There's exceptions: If the name of class ends with

```
class ExampleApp(Screen):
```

kivy is calling the

```
<Example>
```

Please confirm if there's other kivy file in the folder that contains your program.

If error persist try installing other version of kivy

```
pip install --upgrade kivy
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. Unfortunately I tried upgrading kivy and removed and .kv files from the folder with my code yet the error persists. I've edited my original question to include a screenshot of the error for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you see is your graphics system not correctly handling the `SlideTransition` of your `WinManager`. So all the animation steps of the transition are left on the display. You may be able to avoid that by changing the `transition` property of `WinManager`. I would try `NoTransition` first. In your 'kv', change the `WinManager:` rule to:

```
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

WinManager:
    transition: sm.NoTransition()
    Menu:
    Main:
    Setting:
```

Comment: Using FadeTransition helped although I still have problems when I move the pieces. After moving a piece, it appears in it's previous position as well as the new one. i think the canvas is not being cleared properly. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
```

Intel HD Graphics always had a lot of troubles with OpenGL.